# left:0; full stretch without absolute positioning

Tags: css, html, positioning

Just a question.

Is there a way to have a background div stretch the full 100% of the screen without using positioning? The only way I can ever get rid of that bit of padding on either side is to give the div absolute positioning.

Comment: What padding on either side? Sounds like you attack the problem from the wrong direction.

Comment: The "padding" on either side may be default `padding` or `margin` added to the `body` by the browser (which you would have to override in your CSS to be `0`, which is something commonly done). You can use the developer tools (hit F12 for most browsers) to inspect the elements on your page and find where that extra "padding" is coming from.

Comment: haha have you tried body, html { margin: 0; padding: 0; } ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding the below to your CSS:

```
html, body{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
```

## [Example with](http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/bgX28/1/) vs [Without](http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/bgX28/)

Comment: Oh man somehow I missed this answer completely when writing mine! +1

Comment: @SW4 well that would explain why those two are commented out of my body tag. Wow. *Face Palm*